# SQL Server import of file created through bcp

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm currently reviewing how to import a file created from bcp in SQL Server on one computer into my local SQL Server. This is a datafile I received from a 3rd party so I have no idea of the data structure etc. of the information. My SQL Server skills are quite new so please bear with me :) I've reviewd the bcp documents and attempted the following:

```
bcp TestDatabase in File.bcp -T
Results: Invalid Object name 'TestDatabase'
```

I created the test database TestDatabase and tried the query again but with the same response. I then added `-Slocal` and got a login timeout, seems like progress!

I removed the `-T` flag and tried varying combinations of usernames and passwords without any luck.

So I guess to start, is there an underlying issue I'm missing, syntax I'm not following etc. or should I just play around with the creds for my local SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the server, username, and table. Try this:

```
bcp TestDatabase..SomeTableName in File.bcp -S Server -U Username -P Password
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [bcp Utility docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

`-T` means to use Integrated Security (your logged in account)

`-S`is the server name parameter.

These two parameters are not interchangeable.

You can only use the `-U` and `-P` in place of `-T` if you have SQL Authentication turned on (and you shouldn't if you can avoid it)

Finally Chris Shain is correct. You need to specify Schema and table or ViewName, not just a DB Name, as well as the Server (-S)

Also from the documentation (and the point E.J. Brennan was making)

> To import data into a table, you must either use a format file created
>   for that table or understand the structure of the table and the types
>   of data that are valid for its columns.

So you can't expect to just take a file and have bcp magically make a table for you. You need to use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139941.aspx) to help you or some other tool to do that.